# How to identify the source of an event..?

Tags: java, events, swing, awt, jcombobox

Does the method `JComboBox.removeAllItems()` in turn fire an ItemStateChanged event..?
If so, how do i determine weather the event is generated due to the user action or due to the invocation of the method removeAllItems()..?
I have some code in the itemStateChanged() method of a combo box, which will work fine when the user changes the his selection in the combo box, but by the nature of code, it throws a null pointer exception when it is called due to the invocation of removeAllItems() on that combo box. If i can determine the cause for the event to be removeAllItems() method and return the control, then my problem would be solved. How do i do this..?
**UPDATE**
After you people have put up the answers, i used the following code...

```
 @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==branch_list)
            {
                if(!UserConstants.FID.contains("hod"))
                {
                    ignoreEvents=true;//static boolean variable not used by any other methods
                    year_list.removeAllItems();
                    year_list.addItem(" ");
                    sem_list.removeAllItems();
                    sem_list.addItem(" ");
                    branch_list.removeAllItems();
                    branch_list.addItem(" ");
                    if(branch_list.getSelectedItem().equals(" "))
                        return;
                    Iterator year_it=DatabaseConnector.map.get(branch_list.getSelectedItem().toString()).keySet().iterator();
                    while(year_it.hasNext())
                    {
                        year_list.addItem(year_it.next());

                    }
                    ignoreEvents=false;
                }
                return;
            }
            else if(e.getSource()==year_list)
            {
                if((branch_list.getSelectedItem()==null)||branch_list.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(" ")||ignoreEvents)
                return;
                sem_list.removeAllItems();
                section_list.removeAllItems();
                sem_list.addItem(" ");
                section_list.addItem(" ");
                Iterator i=DatabaseConnector.map.get(branch_list.getSelectedItem().toString()).get(year_list.getSelectedItem().toString()).iterator();
                int first=0;
                while(i.hasNext())
                {
                    String cur=i.next().toString();
                    if(first==0)
                    {
                        sem_list.addItem(cur.charAt(0));
                        section_list.addItem(cur.charAt(1));
                        first++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        section_list.addItem(cur.charAt(1));
                    }

                }


            }

        }
I am getting the following error:-  
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeArrayLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:91)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:130)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:544)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:252)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:476)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
    at attendence.Home.itemStateChanged(Home.java:427)
```

and so on...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your best option is to either

1. Remove the listener when you're not interested in the events, even if it is temporary

   ```
   cb.removeItemListener(listener);
   cb.removeAllItems();
   cb.addItemListener(listener);
   ```

   or,
2. Introduce a boolean variable called, say, `ignoreEvents` and do

   ```
   ignoreEvents = true;
   cb.removeAllItems();
   ignoreEvents = false;
   ```

   and let the handler method respect the `ignoreEvents` value.

---

Regarding your update:

You need to have

```
if (ignoreEvents == true)
    return;
```

at the top of your handler. Also, in your

```
if(branch_list.getSelectedItem().equals(" "))
    return;
```

you don't set `ignoreEvents` back to false. You could use a `try` / `finally` to make sure `ignoreEvents` is always set back to false when returning from the method.

Comment: yeah the above two are valid options, thanks. But isn't there a way to know what caused these events ? I expected something like that exists.?

Comment: You won't find any flag containing some `CAUSED_BY_REMOVE_ALL` value or anything. Apart from the constants in the `ItemEvent` class and the `getStateChange` method, you'll have to keep track of this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

did you try `event.getSource()` ?

Comment: That should give the combobox instance in either case, no?

Comment: aioobe is correct using the getSource() returns the instance of combobox but that wont solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for JComboBox.removeAllItem().

```
public void removeAllItems() {
        checkMutableComboBoxModel();
        MutableComboBoxModel model = (MutableComboBoxModel)dataModel;
        int size = model.getSize();

        if ( model instanceof DefaultComboBoxModel ) {
            ((DefaultComboBoxModel)model).removeAllElements();
        }
        else {
            for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
                Object element = model.getElementAt( 0 );
                model.removeElement( element );
            }
        }
    selectedItemReminder = null;
    if (isEditable()) {
        editor.setItem(null);
    }
    }
```

I think you need to add remove Item Listener.

Comment: @sasidhar, this is the above code for removeAllItems().I have couple of suggestions:1.Please make sure that removeAllItems() method is generating an event when it is fired.2.If not, override removeAllItems() method and call removeAllItem() method in JComboBox.3.Then initiate an event in this method itself.Generating event dynamically you can check this link:http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/generic-listener/index.html.